# Web service to interact with sharepoint

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint, download

I am in need of some assistance on a current project. I'm working on a windows service that downloads specific sharepoint files and converts them to a pdf, then emails them to multiple recipients.
The server doesnt have access to the sharepoint library so Microsoft.Sharepoint assembly reference wont work is there another way to access the files and download them? once I get the file (probably word docs) I need to convert them to pdf.

Comment: If you don't have access then you don't have access, and that's that.  You need to get access to the server if you want the files, or have a 3rd party that *does* have access that can get the files and make them available to you.

Comment: To clarify, I have access to the files, but the server that will be running this service doesnt have sharepoint so I cannot use SPListFile or SpFile; things that only exist in Microsoft.Sharepoint library

Comment: That just means you can't use the server object model.  Just to download the files you shouldn't have any *need* to use it.  You can use the client object model if you needed to, but just to download several known files you wouldn't even need that, you can use an HttpWebRequest to just get the files if you know their address.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint supports [WebDAV](http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx?Redirected=true) and that can be used to get individual files provided you know where they are already. However a word of caution, this does require that the domain user that use to get the file must have the "File Browse" permission I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you cannot deploy anything to the Sharepoint server

SSRS ReportViewer which is part is Sharepoint can be used to batch create PDF's as it has an export option, You will find them also as part of Visual studio 2010

http://forums.asp.net/t/1556522.aspx/1

Is an example of this.

Then use the web requests to fetch the file.